# BadLocationException when using Utilities.getRowStart On hit of Enter key

Tags: java, swing, jtextpane

I am using `Utilities.getRowStart` to find out the number of lines in a `JTextPane`. But it gives the `BadLocationException` when I hit the enter key:

> javax.swing.text.BadLocationException: Position not represented by
>   view

Any idea?

```
int offset = pane.getText().length();

while(offset > 0) {

    try {

    offset = Utilities.getRowStart(pane, offset) - 1;

        } catch (BadLocationException e1) {
      // TODO Auto-generated catch block
      e1.printStackTrace();

    }
    lineCount++;
}
```

Comment: add some code to your question

Comment: please find some code

Comment: Actually you need to post an `SSCCE` to demonstrate your problem. If you don't know what an `SSCCE` is then you can search the web.

Answer (score 6):

```
int offset = pane.getText().length();
```

Just a guess that you are working on Windows. That code will return a string containing "\r\n" for every newline character. The Document only uses "\n" so your offset will be greater than the length of the document. Use:

```
int offset = pane.getDocument().getLength();
```

Comment: Thanks Camickr. It works fine now and yes I am using windows.

Comment: @user1815809 consider upvoting and to accept this answer here